# How to install only mysql client on solaris?

Tags: mysql, solaris, solaris-10, sparc

I have a mysql server already running on RHEL 5 server. I have other Solaris 10 and Solaris 11 machines (SPARC based T4-4 servers) which need to connect to the server. I downloaded a pkg (mysql-5.6.23-solaris11-sparc-64bit.pkg.gz) from MySQL CE downloads but it installed client as well as server on the Solaris machine. It only provided me two options: ALL or QUIT.

Are there any packages available for a client only installation? Or are there any configuration parameters for the same?

Answer (score 2):

With Solaris 10 & 11, [pkg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21796/pkg-1.html) should be available. Try to install the `database/mysql-55/client` package:

```
$ pkg publisher
  PUBLISHER         TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
  solaris           origin   online F http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/

$ pkg install database/mysql-55/client
[...]

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for solaris11 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the 5.6.23 MySQL client from OpenCSW, found [here](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWmysql56client/).  [Their package manager](http://www.opencsw.org/manual/for-administrators/getting-started.html) is fairly easy to use.  I have no affiliation with OpenCSW and understand the reasons that other package repositories have become more commercial in nature, but appreciate the work that OpenCSW have done to keep free packages available for Solaris.

Comment: I couldn't get direct links to pkg files on OpenCSW, I think they have just provided links to their repositories. Unfortunately my network is totally offline due to security issues.

Comment: OK I found mysql56client pkg here: http://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/allpkgs/ I'll try it and update with the results.